# Вывожу цены из таблицы с полей, как им присвоить номера и потом по всем ценам этим искать номер, если находит, то выводим цену

Tags: php

Еще учусь в php, такую задачу не делал. Строго не судите.

Вообщем вывожу я цену через функцию которая в модельке и выдергивает цену из бд с полей, все цены в одной таблице но в разных полях.

**Так я вывожу в шаблоне**

```
<?php echo $user->getcatPrice() ?>
<?php echo $user->getcatPrice1() ?>
<?php echo $user->getcatPrice2() ?>
```

Как мне в php сделать проверку и присвоить этим ценам id номер.
**Типа так:**

```
Price - ID: 1
Price1 - ID: 2
Price2  - ID: 3
```

---

```
$user->getcatPrice = 0
$user->getcatPrice1 = 1
$user->getcatPrice2 = 2
```

Суть простая, при выборе категории в форме, я ловлю id категории и передаю его через метод пост в php, далее этот id номер я должен прогонять по этим ценам и если находит совпадения то выводим результат в php, такое не делал, так что пока не могу сообразить как сделать.

Полученный id из формы $data['price'], вот его и надо сверять с номерами цен, но надо им привязать номера к ценам.

Comment: Я ничего не понял

Comment: знаний столько нет чтобы в рамках php использовать формулировку.

Comment: Вы бы лучше описали задачу, которую пытаетесь решить. Может тогда станет понятнее, зачем вы ценам пытаетесь присвоить какие то id, видимо взятые с потолка (а не из БД, где они наверняка уже есть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже помогли, делюсь решением.

Сделал функцию, где я присвоил каждой цене номер.

```
  public function getPriceByID($id)
  {
    $prices = array(
      1 => $this->getcatPrice(),
      2 => $this->getcatPrice1(),
      3 => $this->getcatPrice2(),
      4 => $this->getcatPrice3(),
      5 => $this->getcatPrice4()
    );
    return $prices[$id];
  }
```

Далее, я через метод пост получаю id номер, для того чтобы подставить его и вывести нужную цену по номеру.

```
$price = $user->getPriceByID(3); //допустим 3, значит подгрузит 3 =>$this->getcatDprice()
$price = $user->getPriceByID($data['price']); //а тут я номер из формы подставляю
```

**Еще есть вариант, уже функция в контроллере**

```
$priceFunctions = array(
  1 => 'getcatPrice',
  2 => 'getcatPrice1',
  3 => 'getcatPrice2',
  4 => 'getcatPrice3',
  5 => 'getcatPrice4'
 );
$price = call_user_func(array($priceFunctions[$data['price']]));
```

Comment: Как то плохо помогли вам.. Понятно, что это для самообучения, но.. Как будете действовать, если у вас 100 категорий ? Вручную добавите 100 идентификаторов и функций ? Почему бы не сделать динамически за счет перебора результата запроса ? Типа `foreach ($query as $row) $array[$row->id] = $row->cat_price`. Тем более функция `getPriceByID` могла бы содержать не предопределенный массив, а запрос на выборку конкретного ID из базы данных, раз уж она принимает этот самый идентификатор

Comment: Нет, 100 не будет, это не категории товаров, а категории транспортного средства. По этому я их так добавил, а так бы сформировал бы по другому, не в одной таблице в бд хранил под разными полями, а каждую категорию в отдельном поле, то есть у каждой был бы id свой.

Comment: sousage1212: Кстати да, это тож надо то о чем говоришь.

Comment: Если они у вас хранятся в базе, значит у них есть первичный ключ..надеюсь, что есть ) Вот его и используйте как ID, почему нет )